# Можно ли скрыть токен vk api от хостинга, на котором размещён бот?

Tags: vkontakte-api, хостинг

Наверное, это очень "новичковый" вопрос, но меня немного беспокоит, что при использовании хостинга для бота в ВК, вместе с кодом на хостинг передаётся токен авторизации. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность его скрыть от хостинга или единственный вариант - это выбирать надёжный хостинг?

Comment: Навряд ли хостингу понадобится токен от чьего-то вконтакте. Можете придумать как зашифровать токен и расшифровывать его только ключом, который знаете только вы:)

Comment: @pagislav хостинг всё равно сможет вытащить расшифрованный ключ из своей собственной оперативки